# Using NumericComparer code in C#, why I am getting a conversion error for my List.Sort()?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm using the NumericComparer code located here. It's very easy to add it to a project: [NumericComparer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11016/Numeric-String-Sort-in-C)

I have a List of strings with numbers in them and my code is simply this: `myList.Sort(new NumericComparer());`

The error I am getting is this:

**cannot convert from 'ns.NumericComparer' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer'**

Any ideas why?

Comment: Does your NumericComparer implement IComparer<T> ?

Comment: Here is what the code says... public class NumericComparer : IComparer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the `Sort` method is expecting an implementation of `IComparer<T>` -- generic, with a type parameter, whereas `NumericComparer` implements the non-generic `IComparer` interface.

So, if your list is, say a `List<decimal>`, you need to supply an `IComparer<decimal>`.

You should be able to quickly put together a class that leverages `NumericComparer`:

```
public class GenericNumericComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private static readonly NumericComparer _innerComparer = new NumericComparer();

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        return _innerComparer.Compare(x, y); // I'm guessing this is how NumericComparer works
    }
}
```

So now you can call `myList.Sort(new GenericNumericComparer<decimal>());`

(Note you can actually call your generic class `NumericComparer` too -- it is distinguished by the type parameter. I added "Generic" here for clarity.)

Comment: is there a benefit to doing this over having NumericComparer implement IComparer<T> though?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. Thank you for the code, it works great!

Comment: @Tung I don't know anything about `NumericComparer`. I'm working under the assumption that its utility is being able to compare numeric values of different types, like `int` versus `float`, and it could also be part of a library/dll or otherwise not modifiable.

Comment: @Jay I prefer to not change code that I didn't create to begin with, just to keep external code/extensions clean from me mucking them up, so I think you went the correct route here.